# Sync a git repository with three different origins on Github/Bitbucket

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Imagine I have 4 repositories: [A, B, C, D]
I would like to use a simple git command to update them all at the same time.

I expect to use something like:

```
git push all
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure what would suffice as "without any efforts", but have you tried adding A, B, C as remote repositories of D (via `git add <name> <url>`) and then just pushing to the three of them after commiting (with `git push A master`, `git push B master` and so on)?

Comment: Unclear what you're trying to do... Do you mean that `A`, `B`, and `C` are just different distribution points for exactly the same code?  Or deployment repos on different servers?  Or they contain three different code bases into which you want to merge changes form `D`?

Answer (score 1):

Just add all repos as remotes and make an alias that pushes to all of them like

```
git config alias.push-all '!git push remote-a && git push remote-b && git push remote-c'
```

Then you can use `git push-all` to push to all remotes. If one fails because of non-fast-forward or whatever, solve the issue and just do it again, or manually push to the remotes individually.

Comment: four repositories or four branches?

Comment: OP asked about repositories, not branches

Answer (score 0):

Git itself doesn't have this - its commands only ever apply to things at the repo level - but it's quite simple in bash:

```
for repo in a b c d; do cd ~/$repo && git push; done
```

Replace "a b c d" in there with the repo names or paths, and adjust the cd command accordingly. You could also wrap this in a shebang.